# How do I unhide all rows in VBA from the last row?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

On the spreadsheet, the LastRow is actually 32, but when I run this sub, it's unhiding everything before Row 30, and leaving both 31 and 32 hidden. Any help?

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 1 To LastRow
    Rows(I).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next I
```

Comment: What is the value for `LastRow` when you are debugging? Thought if you want to unhide everything don't loop, `Rows("1:" & LastRow).Hidden = False`

Comment: Is there content all the way down to row `32` in column `D`? Side note: I should be dimmed as `Long` (Excel can handle more rows than `Integer` can count)

Comment: Yes there is content all the way to 32 in D. I'll try taking the loop out

Comment: Taking the loop out worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row` returns last visible row (with data)...

In this case will work:

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count`

Even if I never recommend using it...